# When trigger is executed, nothing is displayed ... why?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

So I've written the following trigger ...

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteOrderTrigger
ON order_details
FOR DELETE

AS
-- Set the variables you'll use during the trigger
DECLARE @orderId int, 
        @productId int, 
        @quantityRemoved int,
        @productName varchar(50),
        @stock int

-- Assign the variables to the selected columns
SELECT @productId = deleted.product_id,
       @productName = products.name,
       @quantityRemoved = deleted.quantity,
       @stock = SUM(products.quantity_in_stock) + @quantityRemoved


FROM deleted 
LEFT JOIN products ON products.product_id = deleted.product_id
LEFT JOIN order_details ON order_details.order_id = deleted.order_id 

WHERE order_details.order_id = @orderId AND products.product_id = @productId

GROUP BY deleted.product_id, products.name, deleted.quantity

GO

-- Test the trigger

DELETE order_details
     WHERE order_id=10001 AND product_id=25
```

So when I call the trigger with the above statement, nothing is returned in the console. Which is odd because I have my select statement written out to return what was being deleted.

However, when I try to return the values that were deleted ... they are actually deleted (so I know that part works) but nothing was returned in the initial trigger.

Is there something wrong in my `SELECT` statement? Or am I missing something with how triggers work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: trigger does not returns any result set. What your delete trigger suppose to do ?

Comment: Does the trigger not return everything from the `SELECT` command?

Comment: Yes. it will read the value and assign to the variable. Triggers are not designed to return result to the client.

Comment: Ah I see your point. So, how do I return a result to the client?

Comment: you don't. Not via trigger. Returning a result, that is the job of a query or stored procedure. Sounds like you need a stored procedure rather than trigger. What are you trying to achieve here ?